# Pegar todas as horas que estão entre a hora inicial e hora final com PHP

Tags: php, datetime, data

Estou desenvolvendo um módulo e preciso pegar todas as horas entre 2 horas, **inicial** e **final**. Exemplo:

```
<?php

$hora_inicial = '08:00';
$hora_final   = '15:00';

?>
```

Então teria que listar

> 08:00 09:00 10:00 11:00 12:00 13:00 14:00 15:00

Como consigo fazer isso com o PHP ?

Comment: Você só precisa da hora? A data não é importante ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou sem PC pra testar, mas asim deve rolar:

```
<?php
$start = '08:12';
$end = '15:30';

$st = explode(':', $start);
$ed = explode(':', $end);

for($hour = $st[0]; $hour <= $ed[0]; $hour++)
{
    for($min = $st[1]; $min < 60; $min += 15)
    {
        if($ed[1] >= $min and $hour <= $ed[0])
            echo "Hour: {$hour}:{$min}<br/>";
    }
}
```

Separo a hora nos dois pontos, e em um for vou da hora inicial ate a final. Lógico se dependendo das horas pode nao acontecer, por exemplo se o intervalo for das 23 às 02, mas como não foi citado na pergunta se pode ocorrer tal caso entao não tratei.

Comment: Seu código funcionou, mas caso tiver minutos ? Tipo `$start = '08:15';'

Comment: Como seria no caso? Pois não foi citado especificamente na pergunta, com minutos a saída seria '8:15', '9:15, e assim por diante? E no caso que citei na pergunta, entraria um intervalo como 23:00 as 02:00? Pois se sim o código da resposta não funcionaria.

Comment: Na verdade o código que estou fazendo ele tem horas que vai de 08:00 até 20:00 e os intervalos são de 15 minutos, ou seja, 08:00, 08:15, 08:45, 09:00 etc... Preciso pegar esses intervalos juntamente com a hora até chegar no $end

Comment: Editei colocando minutos, lembrando que é funcional apenas quando a hora inicial é menor que a final (em algarismo)

Comment: Testei o código e ele ta uns 99%.. O problema é que ele conta até os minutos `45` depois ele pula para a próxima hora +30 do minuto anterior.. Por exemplo: 08:00, 08:15, 08:30, 08:45, **09:15** ... Ele não coloca a hora com **00**

Comment: Fiz uma gambiarra assim: `if($min == 60){$hour = $hour+1;$min = '00';}` e deu certo (além de trocar < 60 por <= 60

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma é converter as horas em segundos e com a [função `range`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php) gerar os horários:

```
function listaHorarios($horaInicio, $horaFinal) {
    // Converte os horários em segundos
    $secsInicio = strtotime($horaInicio) - strtotime('today');
    $secsFinal = strtotime($horaFinal) - strtotime('today');

    // Formato de retorno 
    $formato = function ($horario) {
        return date('g:ia', $horario);
    };

    $horarios = range($secsInicio, $secsFinal, 900); // 15min = 900 (60 * 15)
    return array_map($formato, $horarios);
}
```

Modo de usar:

```
$horaInicio = '08:00:00';
$horaFinal  = '15:00:00';

$horarios = listaHorarios($horaInicio, $horaFinal);

foreach($horarios as $horario){
    echo "$horario \n";
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/HD025P)